# How to iterate through list of hashmap data

Tags: jsp, loops, hashmap

I have list of hashmap. I want to iterate through the data. Kindly help me with an example.
I have a table where I have months on Y axis and the fields like( MS_Target, HSD_Target, ALPG_Target, Lube_Target) on X axis.
My code is as follows:

```
 List<Map<String, Integer>> ListofHash = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();

        {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
          {
          Map<String, Integer> mMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

          mMap.put(String.valueOf(i), Integer.valueOf( + i));

          ListofHash.add(mMap); 
           }
      for (Map<String, Integer> map : ListofHash)
            {
            for (String key : map.keySet())
             {
               System.out.println(map.get(key));
          }
      }

HashMap <String,Integer> april= new HashMap <String,Integer>();

    april.put("aprMS",new Integer(1));
    april.put("aprHSD",new Integer(2));
    april.put("aprAlpg",new Integer(3));
    april.put("aprLubes",new Integer(4));

HashMap <String, Integer> may= new HashMap <String, Integer>();

    may.put("mayMS",new Integer(1));
    may.put("mayHSD",new Integer(2));
    may.put("mayAlpg",new Integer(3));
    may.put("mayLubes",new Integer(4));

}
```

Likewise I have created hashmap for all months.
Also, kindly suggest me what key and value should I take.
Please help me out with an example. 
I have given unique names to all the fields.
eg: apr_MS , apr_HSD etc.
My Table is as follows:

```
Month         MS_Target     HSD_Target     ALPG_Target        Lubes_Target
April
May 
June
July 
August
September
October
November
December
January
February 
March
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator on a hashmap see here :

[Hashmap iteration](http://www.java-examples.com/iterate-through-values-java-hashmap-example)

Comment: Thanks for the post, is the above code that i have mentioned proper??......can u give me a sample code related to my example.